# Access control of AWS SQS subscription for AWS SNS topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs, publish-subscribe, amazon-sns

I have a NodeJS application that publishes message to AWS SNS topic string and a AWS SQS subscription for the same. On the SQS console, I can see the published message. However, I am not clear with the access policy of the SQS queue.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678120/919480) mentions the use of `"Principal": "*"` - but, that is [*very broad*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-security-best-practices.html#ensure-queues-not-publicly-accessible). One could probably use `"Principal" : {"AWS": "*"}`; but, that isn't narrow either.

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1607949016538",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1607949012567",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
        "sqs:SendMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-south-1:463113000000:orders"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Questions**

1. While delivering a message to SQS queue, as a result of subscription, which user is in effect? Same as the one who published to the topic?
2. I could get the messages to flow into the queue *only* when I used `"Principal" : {"AWS": "*"}`. So, how should I define a restrictive policy such that messages are written to queues only as a result of subscription?
3. What is the equivalent in the [AWS SQS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/add-permission.html) to create a queue with `"Principal" : {"AWS": "*"}` permissions?

Answer (score 0):

1. The only user that matters is the one that qualifies for the policy as defined for subscription and SQS access policy.
2. The `Condition` in policy document can make the overall policy restrictive. See example below.
3. [Adding SQS Permissions with conditions using AWS CLI Command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57279182/919480)

Example policy document restricting access to account ID.

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1607960702002",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1607960701004",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
        "sqs:SendMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-south-1:463113000000:orders",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:SourceAccount": "463113000000"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```